# Разделить многостраничный файл в формате doc на отдельные файлы

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

Имеется многостраничный файл в формате doc, нужно при помощи бесплатных библиотек для java, разбить многостраничный файл на отдельные файлы doc, по одной странице. 
  Счастлив буду если дадите ссылку на необходимый материал.

Comment: Ну вы же сами поставили тэг apache-poi. Вот его и используйте. Какую ссылку вы просите? На документацию к нему? Или что, более конкретная какая-то проблема проблема, что-то не получается? Тогда скажите, что именно.

Comment: Я прошу ссылку на документацию или пример, где было бы описано какие библиотеки использовать для обычного копирования одного листа из файла doc, на один лис в другой файл doc.

Comment: Может, это поможет? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130419/how-to-copy-some-content-in-one-docx-to-another-docx-using-poi-without-losin

Comment: Это не подходить так как это копирование полного текста со всеми атрибутами. Это можно сделать и проще в 6 строчек и не через POI. Мне нужно копировать: всё содержание многостраничного файла, по одной странице на файл. При этом Aspose Word я принципиально не хочу использовать, так как оно платное. Спасибо за ссылку.